# jQuery - Get array of multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a global click event handler, which listens for certain items passed to it. The code has this format:

```
$(document).on('click', '#id, .my-class, .my-other-class', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is($(this)[0])) {
      return true;
  }
}
```

however this does not return true only the first object (`#id`) but for any of the selectors (`'#id, .my-class, .my-other-class'`).

I understand this is probably because `$(this)` has only one item in it (0 - which has all of the selectors).

I can get the code to work if I do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#id, .my-class, .my-other-class', function(e) {
  if ($(this).is('#id') {
      return true;
  }
}
```

however I do not want to type the entire selector *again* (call me lazy), especially if I have to type `.my-other-class` (I would never have a class with that large a name but it is a matter of principle).

Thus I tried to use `.split(', ')` however that err'd on `var $this = this.split(', ');` and `var $this = $(this).split(', ');` saying they are not a functions.

**Does anyone know how to get it so that I can type `if ($(this).is($(this)[0]) {}`, or something like that and it will work? Or is this not possible...**

Comment: This should probably be refactored. What you are trying to do makes very little sense.

Comment: Please provide example of your html elements you want to capture

Comment: Can you use `$('#id, .my-class, .my-other-class').on('click', function(){...})` instead?

Comment: @MrvS I'm trying to keep it a global handler which uses if statements to do different things based on what was clicked

Comment: How about using a common class for all elements you want to work with, and use `hasClass` with the original class name as argument inside the callback?